# Apply CSS class to auto generated sortable column in Django

Tags: css, django

In Django, one can use something like `{% sort_column Date date %}` to auto generate a sortable column. This produces

```
<th> <a href="?sortby=date&order=d">Date</a> </th>
```

But how to apply a CSS class to this column so I get something like below?

```
<th class="my-class"> <a href="?sortby=date&order=d">Status</a> </th>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe use the `:nth-of-type()` puesdo selector? i.e. `#myTable th:nth-of-type(3)`

Comment: What's the class for?  In a project I have I've used something like `{{item.pm}}` to set the class based off information I'm also rendering in the table.

Comment: "Django" has no such functionality; you are using some kind of third-party library for this. Which? Maybe it can do what you want already.

Comment: @zgood thanks! i ended up using `nth-child()`